# Opening VS Code remote with URLs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Open a file works fine for local sessions.
Like `vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json:5:10` for a local file, from a local browser.

Or `vscode://file/home/myhome/myProject/package.json:5:10` for a remote file, on a remote server from a browser on the server.

But how about syntax for a vs-code remote ssh session ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the answers listed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4779#issuecomment-1220475865):

```
vscode://vscode-remote/ssh-remote+[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/path/to/file:ROW:COL
```